# SQL - Joining same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Let's say I have a table ***Applications*** as follows

```
ApplicationId INT,
CustomerId INT,
ApplicationDate DATETIME,
IsNewCustomer BOOL
```

I would like to retrieve a list of applications for a given day along with the **IsNewCustomer** flag (which is set if no applications are present for the given CustomerId.

Currently I am using a join on the same table as follows

```
select 
    o.ApplicationId as ApplicationId,
    cast(o.ApplicationDate as date) as ApplicationDate,
    case when n.ApplicationID is not null then 1 else 0 end as IsNewCustomer,
    row_number() over (partition by o.ApplicationId order by o.ApplicationDate desc) as AppSeqNum
from 
    Applications o 
    left join Applications n 
        on n.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
        and n.ApplicationDate < o.ApplicationDate
where
    AppSeqNum = 1
    and ApplicationDate = getdate()
```

I was wondering if there is a better way of achieving the same without having to join on the same table as it doesn't 'feel' like the most elegant solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You could do a subselect instead of joining the same table, but it would probably cost more. I fail to understand why you think it does not feel right. The table that holds the info you need to query is the Applications table so what's the problem about querying it? Another option would be to update the IsNewCustomer as part of the insert/update process in this table so the data would be ready when you need it.

Comment: Nope, you're doing this correctly.  This is the right place to use a self-join.  Don't let self-joins make you self-conscious!

Comment: Hard to know without reverse engineering the query or seeing sample data and desired results, but in SQL Server 2012 there may be more efficient ways of doing this using the new window functions. In earlier versions, this is probably about the best you're going to do. How many rows in the table? How many rows per Customer on average?

Comment: Unless you have a separate `Customer` table to compare against I do not see how you can set *IsNewCustomer* flag the way you described.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, I must add that I am a newbie with SQL and hence wasn't sure about the 'best-practices' and thought there may be a more elegant way to achieve this. @tucaz I agree it will be much easier to have the IsNewCustomer flag controlled in the insert process but someone else owns it, I am merely generating reports :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might use a sub query, but that will just disguise your self join. There is nothing inherently wrong with self joins, they can just get out of hand if you dont have the right indexes and constraints and the table size is limited. One of the reasons you might have heard that self joins are bad is the problem of finding breaks in an otherwise continous monotonic sequence. Say you have a thousand values, with 5 missing and you do a self join (with no indexes or constraints) on value = value +1 then the query optiiser may well decide that there are 1000*1000 possible rows before trying to find the 5 null matches. So if you have a reasonably limited resuts set then no problem.